Multiple unit root tests correction
I have conducted several univariate linear and nonlinear unit root tests and cointegration tests to check the validity of purchasing power parity. Purchasing power parity means cointegration or stationarity. The null typically is a unit root or no-cointegration. Should I apply a correction to account for multiple tests?
